# Rails 2 with_scope in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I'm migrating a Rails 2 app to Rails 4 and I'm having problems porting `with_scope`

Example method in Rails 2:

```
def foo
  with_scope(find: { conditions: { status: 4 }}, create: { status: 2 }) do
    yield
  end
end
```

In Rails 4 I could do something like this:

```
def foo
  where(status: 4).scoping { yield }
end
```

Within this block, when I'd create a new record, the `status` attribute would be assigned to 4, but I need to assign `status` to 2 when creating and `status` to 4 when querying.

How would one do this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but you may be able to use [ActiveRecord::Relation#first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create).

```
def foo
  where(status: 4).first_or_create(status: 2) do
    yield
  end
end
```

As a caveat:

> If a block is provided, that block will be executed **only if a new instance is being created**. The block is **NOT** executed on an existing record.

Comment: For me this isn't relevant anymore, but I'll accept your answer, since it seems it might have been appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the querying part down.  I would typically handle the create case using a default value for the status column.  A migration that includes:

```
change_column_default :table_name, :status, 2
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Right now that project is long gone, but this might have been an all right solution.